# Is the so-called "maximum likelihood" problem for linear regression really a "conditional maximum likelihood" problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, references, linear

I am reading the highly praised “Mathematics for Machine Learning” by  Marc Peter Deisenroth, A. Aldo Faisal, and Cheng Soon Ong.

And in their development of the linear regression model, they write,

> [image]

This “conditional PDF”...$p(y_1, \ldots, y_N|x_1, \ldots, x_N, \theta)$ is not a conditional PDF at all. It is merely carrying the parameters $x_1, \ldots, x_N, \theta$. The only random variable is $y$, which is induced by a zero-mean Gaussian noise, $$y = \theta^Tx + \epsilon$$
Random = Deterministic + Random

The same snippet shows that $x_1, \ldots, x_N$ are not random variables, but merely some vector in $\mathbb{R}^D$. So this makes the maximum likelihood estimation problem an unconditional one. Which is fine.

However, in other texts, they do use conditional PDF, because the author assumes a probability density on each pair of data $(x,y) \sim P$ (as opposed to $y \sim P$ as above). This leads to an alternative development of the maximum likehood problem, for instance, these notes by CMU [Lecture 6: The Method of Maximum Likelihood for Simple Linear Regression](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/06/lecture-06.pdf):

> [image]

Here, this joint PDF is indeed a conditional one. Here $X$ is a random variable. And the calculation follows similarly as in the above reference texts.

So which is it? Is linear regression a maximum likelihood problem or a conditional maximum likelihood problem?

How do you reconcile these two separate and distinct framing of the problem?

Comment: @Aksakal Could you expand on your answer? I am confused whether we are dealing with conditional densities or unconditional densities.

Comment: @Aksakal Would you say that the first notation in the book, $P(y_1, \ldots, y_N| x_1, \ldots, x_N, \theta)$ is or is not a conditional density? I've stated that it is not because there is no random generating process for $x_i$ or $\theta$.

Comment: the notation is conditional, and the thing is conditional if the regressors are random, otherwise it is only conditional on the parameters $\theta$, as opposed to fixed regressors such as in physical experiments where you can set X at what you want

Comment: @Aksakal I only understand conditioning on random variables. I do not understand the meaning of conditioning on deterministic variables. $x_i, \theta$ are not assumed to be generated with any probability distribution or any induced probability distribution, so they are deterministic (albeit, $\theta$ is unknown). The author stressed that we are not conditioning on $\theta$.

Comment: @Aksakal Ok I think its my misunderstanding. In a chapter above this one, it said $(x_n,y_n)$ are sampled from some distribution

Comment: Technically, people write the likelihood function as a function of the parameters given the data. During MLE you're maximizing the likelihood function to find the values of theta that are most likely, given your data. So all MLEs are conditional (conditional on the data). So I would just say that regression is a maximum likelihood problem and leave it at that. It is usually implied that it is conditional on the data. Said another way, I was taught that L(theta | x ) = \prod_{i=1}^N f( x | theta ). Remember data is always given, parameters are estimated.

Comment: @M.Austin, data is not always given, not all data, anyways. If you're running a physics experiment, X is usually not given, it's set by you.

Comment: @Aksakal - yes you are right. I misspoke. I was just referring to a simple OLS case. I was just trying to give the poster a simple intuition that in OLS you have data and you are trying to estimate your slope and intercept. Sorry for the confusion.